# Animate threejs camera to a previously saved matrix

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm saving a threejs camera matrix using the following method:

```
let cameraMatrix = camera.matrix.toArray();
```

Then loading it afterwards using these methods:

```
camera.matrix.fromArray( cameraMatrix );
camera.matrix.decompose( camera.position, camera.quaternion, camera.scale );
```

It works perfectly well but I can't figure out how to animate its way to the previously saved matrix so it looks stylish.

I looked into tween.js but it seems to work for animating an object but I need to animate the camera (entire scene), not an individual object.

Comment: The camera _is_ an object. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47844030/using-tween-to-animate-a-camera/47848415#47848415).